# Artifactory S3 Object Storage, automatic migration, _pre directory location (typo in doc?)

Tags: artifactory

I'm trying to convert my binary store from the local Artifactory filesystem ($ARTIFACTORY_HOME/data/filestore) to S3 object storage.

According to this doc: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/S3+Object+Storage#S3ObjectStorage-AutomaticFilestoreMigration(Recommended), within the $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/data/eventual/ directory I should create
"*A link with the name _pre that points to the $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/data/_pre directory*"

There is no such _pre directory within the $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/data directory, however there is an empty _pre directory within $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/data/filestore.

Does the documentation have a typo, or should I create a directory $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/data/_pre ?

Comment: Answering my own question...

Doc appears not to have a typo.  I created the link as indicated in the doc. Restarting Artifactory without also creating the (missing) $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/data/_pre directory caused a problem: 
`Unable to create directory /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/data/eventual/_pre`
Creating the missing directory and restarting Artifactory appears to have yielded a successful migration of binary objects to the S3 bucket.